# How to crop in Adobe Acrobat X(10)?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, crop

I'm unable to get the crop functionality to work at all in Adobe Acrobat 10, and their help is only online and is completely non-helpful.

Can someone explain exactly how to crop an image in Adobe Acrobat X?

[Related](https://superuser.com/questions/127568/how-to-crop-permanently-in-acrobat)

Comment: You cant get it to do anything, or its not really getting deleted?

Comment: I wasn't able to even get the crop box dialog up, I can now do that for the page, and have `set clip` on an image, but it won't let me resize the clip box.

Comment: @soandos, forgot to @ you on the last message.  I've now solved my problem, but will upvote and accept a complete answer, so future visitors will be able to find out how to work it.

Comment: Just post it yourself, and mark it as answer. I dont know what the issue is.

Comment: @soandos, I'll do that eventually if no one else wants to, but it's not an issue thing, it just needs to be a How to Use thing, and a good answer will take some time to put together (certainly more time than Adobe wanted to put into it).