# How to recover from a "cropped" PDF?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

In this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/127568/how-to-crop-permanently-in-acrobat), it discusses how to really crop a PDF.

I am asking, for an already cropped PDF with the cropped information still being hidden, is it possible to recover them? So that when I open the recovered PDF, it SHOWs all the hidden information.

I know how to "see" the hidden information using "Remove Hidden Information".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Cropbox to the Mediabox, and you have uncropped the document. This works as long as the document has just been cropped.

Comment: "has just been cropped" has to be the key.